# Can't fetch from old-releases.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt, release-management

Has the package management for old unsupported systems been changed?

I have my `sources.list` set up to fetch from `old-releases.ubuntu.com` but all I get when doing an `apt-get` is:

```
Could not connect to old-releases.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.17), connection timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

The website seems down.

There is a website that can check it for you: 
http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com

This could be permanent but I do not remember there to be a notice it would be taken down. Maybe it is down for maintenance.